# SSDT for visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssdt-bi

Does this exist?  I can't find SSDT for visual studio 2015? anyone know if this exists or is/when it is going to be available?

must be a way of developing in SSIS/RS in Visual studio 2015?

EDIT

Found this, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/ probably the best place to keep checking!

Comment: Usually they ship with the next version trailing the release of Visual Studio 2015. have you tried installing the latest preview release of SQL Server 2016 ? http://sqlmag.com/blog/what-coming-sql-server-2016-business-intelligence

Comment: No but I'll look at it thanks.  I know they moved SSDT/BIDS away from SQL and as a stand alone installation for visual studio.  Wish they would stick with a name and install method!

Comment: SSDT is included as an optional feature when installing Visual Studio 2015, even the Community Edition. But BI (SSIS/SSRS) support is not included. I haven't found the BI stuff yet.

Comment: This is by far the most frustrating thing about vs for the last 3 releases of VS!!

Comment: I think it is coming in the full release due out next month.

Comment: I've read (can't find link sorry) that SSDT-BI is released corresponding with new versions of SQL Server and NOT Visual Studio.  If that's true we shouldn't expect a VS 2015 version of SSDT-BI until SQL Server 2016 is released.

Comment: Request to reopen because this is not a question about tools and personal preferences but about supported development stacks, one that has been plaguing generations of business intelligence developers and as such it is valid and in scope for this site.

Answer (score 10):

SSDT 2015 for visual studio 2015 is found here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx

Comment: it would be great if this were available in visual studio's tools/extensions dialog.

Comment: now https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383.aspx  (and still no subfolders in projects!)

Comment: @Spongman It will be available in the Extensions dialog after General Availability (June 1, 2016) and a few extra days for getting it through the pipeline (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501 states "Since SQL Server tooling is included in VS, the updates will be pushed through VS Update and users will be prompted when VS is open"). Manual download is available from the same page.

Answer (score 7):

There is now support available for developing SSIS/SSRS/SSAS in Visual Studio 2015 through the October 2015 preview of SSDT.
It appears, from the wording on the download page, the distinction between SSDT and SSDT-BI is finally history!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/10/27/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-october-2015.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Comment: SSDT, including the BI tooling, are now GA: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/06/01/sql-server-data-tools-ga-update-for-june-2016/

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a regular SSDT, I think you can find it easily somewhere on the internet.

If you're looking for SSDT WITH! SSIS or any BI(Business Intelligence) components, I think you'll need SSDT-BI which is currently available only at VS 2012 and 2013. You can install SSDT in VS 2015 but without some BI components. I guess?

Comment: This is correct.  The distinction between SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) and SSDT-BI (SQL Server Data Tools for Business Intelligence) can be very confusing.  SSDT gives you schema designers and SQL script editing.  Only SSDT-BI allows you to work with SSIS or RPT (SQL Server Reporting Services) projects.  See my comment above as I don't believe we'll get SSDT-BI until SQL Server 2016 is released.

Answer (score 3):

Past versions of SSDT-BI for Visual Studio have been released a year or more after a new version of Visual Studio was released. If the releases continue in that pattern, we might expect the VS 2015 version of SSDT-BI to be released about a year from now.

Answer (score 1):

From the SSDT team about the SQL Server Data Tools Preview update for October 2015:

- SSAS and SSRS support 2008 all the way to 2016 CTP3.0.
- SSIS currently supports 2016 CTP3.0 only. But the support for SSIS 2012 and 2014 is coming as well. SSIS has some complex scenarios to address before it can be previewed and the team is working really hard to deliver this scenario.

So still no full SSIS support! Maybe in the november update next week.